# Recovering data from an Encrypted iTunes Backup that's missing the Manifest.db

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, data-recovery

Is there a method to recover from an encrypted iTunes backup if it's missing its manifest.db file?

I have the backup password and everything. There's a couple of third party tools that can read an encrypted iTunes Backup, but they fail if the backup is missing its manifest.db file. (iMazing, iPhone Backup Extractor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, part of the encryption keys (one for each individual file) is stored in the Manifest.db. The backup password is used to unwrap (unlock) those keys with some more parts from the Manifest.plist, but doesn't help derive the missing key parts. I wish I had better news, but an encrypted backup missing either one of those Manifest files isn't decryptable.

Just to make sure, is there a subfolder inside the backup named "Snapshot"? If so, we should triple-check for the Manifest.db in there.

Comment: No there is no snapshot folder. 
So each file has a different encryption key that is used to encrypt the file?

Comment: Correct, a key is generated randomly, one per file, then wrapped using AES key wrap and stored in the Manifest.db. So currently, there's no feasible way to decrypt files in the backup without the Manifest.db, Manifest.plist, and backup password all three combined.